# Error after using package german

Tags: errors, miktex, texstudio, german

I tried to use the package `german`. As soon as I implemented it in my header file. I couldn't create a pdf anymore and can't build the project now. I removed the line I entered but it is still not working.

the error messages are:

```
Argument of \scr@load@hook has an extra }. \begin{document}
Paragraph ended before \scr@load@hook was complete. \begin{document}
Missing\endcsname inserted. \begin{document}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \begin{document} Missing number, treated as zero. \begin{document}
Missing { inserted. \begin{document}
Missing \endcsname inserted. \begin{document}
Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}
Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 3.
```

I am using TeXstudio and MiKTeX.

Comment: Delete all generated files (.aux etc.) and try again. If you want to get the `german` package working, you will need to provide a short example code that reproduces the problem. Without that, it's likely to be impossible for anyone to help you.

Comment: Remove the .aux files and try again

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You should use `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` instead of the `german` package. NEVER use that obsolete package.

Answer (score 0):

TeXnician is right, but this works fine....

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{german}   % obsolete, don't use, but works anyway
\begin{document}
kein Problem
\end{document}
```

As an aside, it has nothing to do with your editor (texstudio) or your installation (miktex).  This also illustrates why it's important to include a complete minimal working example (MWE) like I did in my answer.

Comment: I really don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: Can't stick this in a comment.